# resize font in ivy-posframe

Tags: fonts, ivy

i'm tryinng to set the font in ivy-posframe and no result. i have try code adapt to another cases, like:

```
(defun text-scale-twice ()(interactive)(progn(text-scale-adjust 0)(text-scale-decrease 2)))
(add-hook 'neo-after-create-hook (lambda (_)(call-interactively 'text-scale-twice)))
```

or

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-minibuffer-setup)
(defun my-minibuffer-setup ()
       (set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
          '((default :height 0.8))))
```

in the last resizing the minibuffer is not enough,
any idea?